# what do we call the events that one of them is subset of the other

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

how to describe the relationship (exclusive, inclusive,.. etc) between two events that one is a subset of the other?

example: if 'event 1' happened then 100% 'event 2' have happened.
[image: event 1 in part of event 2]

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If $E_1\subseteq E_2$ then $E_1$ is a subevent of $E_2$ (*which is equivalent to saying that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are both events of the same sample space and $E_1$ is a subset of $E_2$ when thought of as sets*).  It follows that if $E_1\subseteq E_2$ then $Pr(E_2\mid E_1)=1$

Comment: @JMoravitz, is there a name to this relationship in English? 'Subset events' or 'Subevents' for example?

Comment: Did I not make that clear?  If $E_1\subseteq E_2$ then $E_1$ is a subevent of $E_2$.  That was my first sentence in my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah then subevents, I guess my mind was looking for something else. Thanks.